# Does the php code always mix with html code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jsp, web

In web development, does the backend code always mix with the front code at some point? Checking jsp and some php I see that the code is usually mixed, is this a bad practice or should you always avoid using javascript as an intermediary?

Comment: Check out MVC frameworks like Laravel. Separates models (data) from the logic (controllers) and the presentation (views).

Comment: @Artistan so the answer is "go use a framework?"

Comment: @dbf , often mixed, frameworks “help” to prevent to actual logic in your presentation. Much easier to maintain and update logic and to revamp the presentation when split up in a logical manner

Comment: you can always do MVC/MVVM or other structure pattern logic without frameworks

Comment: thanks, i will start to review laravel

Answer (score 0):

Normally it depends on what you really want to do. But they are usually mixed

Answer (score 0):

PHP was developed as a templating language for web, so basically it is what it was created for. But you might notice that in modern projects PHP used mostly as an API backend for Javascript application. In such cases, it will not be mixed.
It seems to me that it depends on the project type. But even if you do not use modern JS frameworks try to separate business and frontend logic. Check the MVC architecture or DDD.